# angularjs check if ng-model != isFinite

Tags: css, angularjs

I have the word infinity appear in my output and I am trying to change its color when it becomes and actual number.

So when I check to see if it isFinite it changes to orange, but then when it actually becomes a number- I cant get it to change to black. I am so close with this, am I writing this wrong?

`<span ng-model="users2" ng-class="{'test3':users2 === isFinite , 'test2':users2 !== isFinite}" ng-hide="!myVar" style="font-size:28px; color:purple" >`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I writing this wrong?

Yes... several issues

`isFinite` is  function first off. Also it is in global namespace whereas angular expressions are evaluated against scope variables

You would need to define `isFinite(testValue)` in angular scope (controller) to use it in the view

```
// be sure to inject $window in controller
$scope.isFinite = $window.isFinite
```

And in view would be:

```
ng-class="{'test3':isFinite(users2) , 'test2':!isFinite(users2)}"
```

Reference [MDN isFinite()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite)

Comment: See comment that you need to inject $window in controller

Comment: ok I have injected it, but it still does not change colors when it actually becomes a finite. It stays same color. So when it is at infinity and changes to an actual # no change.

Comment: Changing color is one thing, adding class is another. Does class change in live html when you inspect it in browser dev tools?

Comment: The class does not change in the live html

Comment: [Works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UVUI9VDmOE2u96Pvahuc?p=preview). Fork and update with code you are using that isn't working

Comment: Might not be right test function `isFinite` depending on values used. Did you read docs I linked to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114441/discussion-between-vzupo-and-charlietfl).